# Can't substitute LGR font with fbb if [proportional] option given

Tags: fonts, bugs

Running pdflatex, I'm unable to substitute a Greek font with the fbb package if I give the [proportional] option to the package.  Without that option, the substitution is fine.

Is there a reason this doesn't work, or is it possibly a bug in the fbb package.  If the later, how do I report it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\usepackage[proportional]{fbb}
%\usepackage{fbb}                             % works fine without option
\substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{Tempora-TLF}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\textgreek{αβγδεζηθ}
\end{document}
```

I get this warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LGR/fbb-LF/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `LGR/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 12.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the proportional option fbb redefine \rmdefault in \AtEndPreamble, so you should postpone the substituation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\usepackage[proportional]{fbb}

\AtEndPreamble{\substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{Tempora-TLF}}

\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\textgreek{αβγδεζηθ}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also `\AtBeginDocument` works. In my opinion, `babel` should be loaded earlier; my preference is `fontenc`, `inputenc` and `babel` as early as possible, in that order. There's no need to explicitly load `LGR`, by the way (with an up-to-date TeX system).

Comment: Wow, would have never figured that out.  I don't know Tex well enough to read most package files, but I was looking for something messing with the LGR encodings.  Still, this feels like a package bug.